# Displaying photos that fill the grid - regardless of aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a photo gallery as a home learning project in react. I am able to display the photos in a grid:

[image]

Using this code:

```
const Container = styled.div`
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 10px;
justify-items: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
`

const PhotoWrapper = styled.div`
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 200px; /* set a fixed height for each grid item */
`

const Photo = styled.img`
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
height: 100%; /* make the image fill the height of the grid item */
`

const Home = () => {

       return (
        
            <Container>
                {imagesData.map((image) => <PhotoWrapper><Photo src={image.imageUrl} /></PhotoWrapper> )}
            </Container>
           
    )
}

export default Home
```

That's NEARLY how I want it, but... I want it to be more like Flickr. Who do an AMAZING job at filling the grid without stretching photos (That I can tell).

Example:
https://www.flickr.com/prints/discover

[image]

How do they manage to keep the rows the same length, and height? Is there some awesome CSS trick? Or is there maybe a load of backend work to calculate sizes and see what fits? How can I display my grid like that?

Edit: The solution accepted is amazing for what I need. Here's what it looks like for me now:

[image]

The only issue is when a small number of photos go onto the last row. The get cropped a lot, ad hard to see what they are. Is there a :last type class that could help this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using DevTools to look at the HTML and CSS? If you haven't, I think you should. You can check other sites as well, such as [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org).

Comment: I have but I can't see any resizing happening. It just seems to set the width of each photo. I can't see how they're making all lengths of random sized photos, for each row, sum up to the width of the row. I'm guessing some backend processing that calculates what photos can fit on each row. I was hoping for some clever CSS class. As I said. Learning project - and Flickr's code looks baffling.

Comment: There’s a lot more going on in Flickr than just CSS. I notice that the rows are all of **similar** height, but they are **not exactly** the same. I presume they have a (complicated) back-end algorithm which selects images of the correct size to fill each row, avoiding the need to crop any of the images. But if I were going to build something like this, I would opt for a simpler strategy where I would make all the rows the same height, I would make each row a flexbox (no grids anywhere), and I would resort to cropping one image per row (using `object-fit`) so that all rows have equal width.

Comment: Yup, I agree. It's pretty well done, but complex. I think what you mention is my next bet option. Is there a way to make all the images, regardless of height and width, fill the white space? So I can force a width, but then if I have a portrait, then a landscape, and then a portrait, aligned top - can I make the image that renders below the landscape one - fit up against the bottom of the landscape one above? So, variable heights in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `object-fit` and `flex-wrap`. Note that only a portion of an image will be displayed if it doesn't fit.

First, we need a `#gallery` with multiple `.item`s:

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/img.png">
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

As the number of images and their width cannot be predicted, we make `#gallery` a `flex-wrap: wrap` container.

```css
#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

We then allow `.item`s to expand as much as they'd like on their row, which has a fixed height of `100px` or another value of your choice:

```css
.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Finally, set [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) for the images. This, along with `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, ensure that they will always touch two sides and overflow the other two:

```css
.item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try it:

(The last images might be a bit too wide, since we are displaying a limited number of images, but infiniscroll is normally used to overcome this.)

```js
/**
 * Randomly add 15 - 44 images, of which sizes are in range 100 - 499.
**/

const gallery = document.querySelector('#gallery');

const l = 15 + Math.random() * 30 | 0;

for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  
  const [width, height] = [0, 0].map(
    _ => 100 + Math.random() * 400 | 0
  );
  
  wrapper.classList.add('item');
  img.src = `https://picsum.photos/${width}/${height}`;
  
  wrapper.appendChild(img);
  gallery.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```css
#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}

.item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

Comment: That is AMAZING!!! I'm going to try it now in my project and see how it goes. If that works - you're a genius!

Comment: If I could give more points, I would. That's damn near perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to make the last row NOT do it? Reason is if I land up with only one image on the last row, it stretches it to the full width, and you can;t really see what the photo is of. Even if there's just two or three. I've added it to the question as an edit.

Comment: @Craig You can set a `max-width` on them, but the value would depend on how you calculate it, likely in JS.